# Parsing the byte array into XML file

Tags: java, xml

I am getting issue while parsing the byte Array to XML file.

I am getting garbage data in prologe:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\\kerning1\expnd0\expndtw0  ?>\
```

How can I resolve this?

The code to convert byteArray to XML file:

```
public static File convertByteArrayToXMLFile(byte[] byteArray, String myFile) {
    String extension = ".xml";
    String filename = myFile+extension;
    File f = new File(filename);

    try {
      f.createNewFile();

      // write the bytes in file
      FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
      fo.write(byteArray);
      fo.close();
      return f;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: That garbage looks like a RTF file. Whatever you're reading is not a proper XML file at all. The problem is not in the code you showed, but wherever `byteArray` comes from. (besides there's no need to call `f.createNewFile()` before opening a `FileOutputStream`, the stream will create the file if necessary).

Comment: Hi @JoachimSauer
I am uploading RTRAN file which contains XML data in S3 bucket and then I am downloading that file from s3 bucket as byteArray.

Comment: I don't know what RTRAN is, but I can tell you that what you have here looks like someone wrote a RTF file (probably on a Mac) and that RTF file *contains XML text*, but that's not an XML file. So instead of saving the file as "rich text" (or however the editor calls that format) it should be saved as "plain text" (or similar) instead. Ideally you'd create that file with an editor (or IDE) that actually understands XML. The file on S3 is already wrong, it's not XML.

Comment: The garbage is in your byte array. So the problem is not in the code above.